# weird ROC curve prediction

Tags: roc

I have the following predictions (prediction_svm_linear) from an svm model and I want to plot the ROC curve using the pROC package in R. I get AUC 100%, which is not possible because based on the confusion matrix I don't have perfect prediction. Clearly  I am missing something and probably I don't fully understand how ROC curves work, could you please explain to me why this might be happening?

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
Prediction Cancer Normal
Cancer     11      0
Normal      3      5

           Accuracy : 0.8421          
             95% CI : (0.6042, 0.9662)
No Information Rate : 0.7368          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.2227          

              Kappa : 0.6587          
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.2482          

        Sensitivity : 0.7857          
        Specificity : 1.0000          
     Pos Pred Value : 1.0000          
     Neg Pred Value : 0.6250          
         Prevalence : 0.7368          
     Detection Rate : 0.5789          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5789          
   Balanced Accuracy : 0.8929          

   'Positive' Class : Cancer
```

Here is my code:

```
library(pROC)
    testData_class = c(rep(c("Normal", "Cancer"), c(5, 14)))
    prediction_svm_linear = data.frame(Cancer = c(0.11766249, 0.04765463, 0.08749940, 0.01715765, 0.10755376, 0.28358435, 0.37478957, 0.90603193, 0.91077112, 0.68602820, 0.64783894, 0.67916187,0.38785763, 0.66440580, 0.51897036, 0.93484214, 0.91719866, 0.83239007, 0.63491027), Normal = c(0.88233751, 0.95234537, 0.91250060, 0.98284235, 0.89244624, 0.71641565, 0.62521043, 0.09396807, 0.08922888, 0.31397180, 0.35216106, 0.32083813,0.61214237, 0.33559420, 0.48102964, 0.06515786, 0.08280134, 0.16760993, 0.36508973))

    result.roc.model1 <-  roc(testData$class, prediction_svm_linear$Cancer, 
                            levels = rev(levels(testData$class)))


>result.roc.model1
Call:
roc.default(response = testData$class, predictor = prediction.prob.b5_svm_linear$Cancer,     levels = rev(levels(testData$class)))

Data: prediction.prob.b5_svm_linear$Cancer in 5 controls (testData$class Normal) < 14 cases (testData$class Cancer).
Area under the curve: 1
```

Comment: On what threshold is your confusion matrix based? Can you show how you generated it? Obviously the ROC curve is telling you there is a better threshold...

Comment: I haven't set any threshold for the confusion matrix. This is the code: 
`confusionMatrix(testData_class, prediction_svm_linear)`

Comment: From the caret package?

Comment: Also please check your code, it doesn't run at the moment and makes it very difficult to know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I would suspect that your misusing the `confusionMatrix` function from the `caret` package. According to the documentation, the second factor should be "[a factor of classes to be used as the true results](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995)", while your comment suggests that you are passing a `data.frame` with continuous predictions. Not only does it differ from the required format, but it should also be your first argument.

You should use something like this instead:

```
predictions <- ifelse(prediction_svm_linear$Cancer > 0.2, "Cancer", "Normal")
confusionMatrix(predictions, testData_class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i might have confused you but here is all the information

## **Binary prefiction:**

`prediction_svm = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Normal", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer")`

## **Base truth:**

`testData_class = c(rep(c("Normal", "Cancer"), c(5, 14)))`

## **Probability predictions**

`prediction_svm_linear.prob = data.frame(Cancer = c(0.11766249, 0.04765463, 0.08749940, 0.01715765, 0.10755376, 0.28358435, 0.37478957, 0.90603193, 0.91077112, 0.68602820, 0.64783894, 0.67916187,0.38785763, 0.66440580, 0.51897036, 0.93484214, 0.91719866, 0.83239007, 0.63491027), Normal = c(0.88233751, 0.95234537, 0.91250060, 0.98284235, 0.89244624, 0.71641565, 0.62521043, 0.09396807, 0.08922888, 0.31397180, 0.35216106, 0.32083813,0.61214237, 0.33559420, 0.48102964, 0.06515786, 0.08280134, 0.16760993, 0.36508973))`

and I am building the confusion matrix with this command:

`confusionMatrix(prediction_svm, testData$class)`

```
library(pROC)
    result.roc.model1 <-  roc(testData$class, prediction_svm_linear.prob$Cancer, 
                            levels = rev(levels(testData$class)))


>result.roc.model1
Call:
roc.default(response = testData$class, predictor = prediction.prob.b5_svm_linear$Cancer,     levels = rev(levels(testData$class)))

Data: prediction.prob.b5_svm_linear$Cancer in 5 controls (testData$class Normal) < 14 cases (testData$class Cancer).
Area under the curve: 1


>result.coords.model1 <- coords(  result.roc.model1, "best", best.method="closest.topleft",ret=c("threshold", "accuracy"))

>result.coords.model1
```

> ```
> threshold  accuracy 
> 0.2006234 1.0000000
> ```